# Ansible module to fail when IP's are reachable

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a scenario in playbooks when I see a certain node is Up it should fail giving a warning message to the user to "power off node are try re-run".I have used fail module but not sure which conditional to add.

```
- command: ping -c3 {{ server1-ip }}
 tags: cluster

- command: ping -c3 {{ server2-ip }}
 tags: cluster

- debug:
   msg: "The nodes {{ server1-ip }} and {{ server2-ip }} are pingable, please make sure to turn off the node before re-run else cluster fails"
   verbosity: 1
 tags: cluster

- name: Fail if servers are pingable
 fail:
   msg: "{{ server1-ip }} and {{ server2-ip }} are ON , make sure to turn off all nodes 
         before deployment"
 when: << >> #what conditional fits better here? 
 tags: cluster
```

For now, I'm thinking to slurp the o/p of the `command` module , meaning if I get 0% loss, that means its pinging. so thought of including

```
- name: Test the connectivity for Servers
  command: ping -c3 {{ server1-ip }}
  register: ping_results
  failed_when: "0% packet loss in ping_results"       
  tags: cluster
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: First, use the `ping` module with `failed_when: false`.  Then put `when: ping_results.rc == 0` in your fail module.

Comment: @Jack thanks yeah thats another way to test, when you say `failed_when: false` that means `ping` result is a success and next you use another module to mention why its failing.

Comment: Right.  In your case, you actually WANT the `ping` module to fail, so it's failing is actually success!

Comment: yes, that is exactly my use-case.

Comment: OK -- a couple changes.  Needed `any_errors_fatal: true` on the `fail` module, to keep the playbook from going to the next play.

Answer (score 2):

Based on our discussion in the comments, we have two plays.  The first ensures the target hosts are down, and the second runs the install from `localhost`:

```
- name: Ensure all target hosts are down
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: ping hosts
    ping:
    failed_when: false
    ignore_unreachable: true
    register: ping_result

  - name: fail if host is up
    fail:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} is alive."
    when: not ping_result.unreachable
    any_errors_fatal: true

- name: Run install from localhost
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: This is where we would run install
    meta: noop
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below logic and its working now,

```
- name: Test the connectivity for Servers
  command: ping -c3 {{ server1-ip }}
  register: results
  failed_when:
    - '"0% packet loss" in results.stdout'    
  tags: cluster
```

We can also use:

```
- name: Test the connectivity for servers
  command: ping -c3 {{ server1-ip }}
  register: results
  tags: cluster

- name: If servers are ON fail with an error message
  fail:
    msg: "{{ server1-ip }} and {{ server2-ip }} are ON please switch it off"
  when: '"0% packet loss" in results.stdout'
  tags: cluster
```

This means if the above servers are up, this playbook fails. I'll appreciate any other logic.